# How to move <title> inside the <head>?

Tags: php, html

In my website I have the same header for all pages. So I use the `include` function for the header. This includes all the `<head></head>`.

Because the `<title>` is variable depending on the page, I have put it just after the `<body>`.

I know this is wrong. How can I fix this and move the variable `<title>` inside the standard `<head>` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

In the code that you include for the header, use a placeholder for the title:

```
<head>
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
...
</head>
```

Then, in your page-specific code, just before the `include` statement, populate the `$pageTitle` variable:

```
$pageTitle = "Your Title";
include...
```

To make your included code more robust, consider setting a default title if none is provided:

```
<title><?php echo isset($pageTitle)? $pageTitle: 'Default Title'; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a title variable before including header:

```
$title = 'Whatever you want';
include('header.php');
//rest of your page
```

Inside `header.php`:

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    <!-- the rest of your stuff -->
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a variable inside of your header file for your title, then define that value in your page *before* you include the header:

Inside your include:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?= $page_title; ?></title>
```

Inside your main file:

```
<?php
$page_title = 'My page title';
include('header.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your included file only contain the *contents* of the `<head>` tag, and not the tag itself.

This way you can include the file between `<head></head>` tags and also have the title differ for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly set the page title in a variable ahead of your include, and have this in the head:

```
<title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($pageTitle, ENT_QUOTES); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a PHP variable above the header include such as

```
$title = 'test page';
```

Then in the header you use

```
<title>Main site title | <?php isset($title) ? $title : 'No title set' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have things set up, you may have to set the title before you call your include.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$title = "My Page Title";
include('path-to-your-header.php);
```

Your header would look something like this then:

**PHP:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title="<?php echo($title); ?>">
...
</head>
```

Or, if you are using a framework (codeigniter for example) you can use a tempalte - then in your controller method(s) you can set the page title.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Controller
public function index()
{
    $data['page_title'] = 'Your Page Title';
    $data['main_content'] = 'home'; // page content
    $this->load->view( 'templates/public', $data ); // page template
}

// Tempalte
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo ($page_title !== '' ) ? $page_title . ' | ' . SITE_NAME : '' . SITE_NAME; ?></title>
...
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->load->view( 'header' ); ?>
    <?php echo $this->load->view( $main_content ); ?>
    <?php echo $this->load->view( 'footer' ); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

in page.php

```
<?php    
$title = 'This title';
include('header.php');
?>
```

in header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : '' ?></title>
</head>
<!-- rest of code goes below here -->
```